# Help with Shell Scripts, creating a list of options for users

Tags: linux, script

I am trying to teach myself to write Shell Scripts on my Raspberry Pi, but I am struggling to make a menu where a user can choose from these different options:

- display a list of current users
- display a list of all files including hidden files in the home directory
- output a calendar for the current month
- quit the script.

Comment: Perhaps if you post the code you are currently using someone could help.  Have you looked at the whiptail package?

Comment: I don't really know where to start I'm afraid, I was hoping someone would help me out with the code.

Comment: This question might fit better on [unix.se], as that is a *nix-oriented site. This site is Raspberry Pi-specific and your question is a more generic Linux issue than Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

maybe if you try using a while loop, and use 'do'. Then use 'case in'.